# How can I speed up this bake script I wrote?

Tags: python, scripting, texture-baking, baking, procedural

I wrote a script that handles baking objects textures into an image node that is then attached back to a bsdf node. It works well for the most part. It's just really slow. Like 45 seconds - 90 seconds for the baking process. I'm wondering if there is a way to optimize the script I wrote, or is this just as good as it gets? The problem I'm trying to solve here is that I have a collection of objects that I need to iterate through and bake each one. The actually project this is for has hundreds of sub-collections and objects. At its current output speed for each object, it will take days or even a week to bake all the objects lol.

[image]

Any advice or feedback is super appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/why-is-texture-baking-so-mind-meltingly-slow/5653
This post actually solved my problem. I was focused on the script being the issue, where the slow render was a result of the sample count of my render. I reduced it to 16, and it has dramatically reduced the bake time.